# Камера уходит под землю при нажатии W, хотя должна лететь прямо

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема заключается в том, что я хочу управлять камерой на WASD, и при этом камера должна быть немного наклонена вниз. Я написал код, который позволяет управлять этой камерой, но при наклоне и нажатии на кнопку "W", камера начинает уходить под землю, а должна продолжать лететь прямо. Что мне нужно поменять в моём коде?

```
public class CameraMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float horizontalInput;
    public float verticalInput;
    private float speed = 30.0f;

    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("HorizontalUI");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("VerticalUI");
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * verticalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * horizontalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, создать объект-пустышку, в котором будет лежать объект с наклонённой камерой и двигать непосредственно пустышку.

Comment: Теперь у меня перепутаны кнопки WASD, хотя до этого всё было нормально

Comment: Перепроверьте поворот объекта и камеры, такого в принципе не должно быть.

Comment: Всё, исправил, теперь работает как надо. Спасибо большое.